# What is the problem in the for loop of my python pizza code not working?

Tags: python, loops, debugging

Hi I have created this basic python code which asks for the favourable pizza people want including the toppings

I have tried modifying the loops but it gives an error, if it works, it doesn't give an appropriate answer.

'''

```
print("Hello.\nWelcome to Pizzeria World")
Cheese_Types = ['Mozzarella', 'Parmesan', 'Ricotta', 'Feta', 'Blue Veined', 'Cheddar', 'Gouda', 'Cottage', 'Goat', 'Halloumi', 'Kalari', 'Scamorza', 'Bocconcini', 'Mascarpone', 'Gorgonzola', 'Grana Padano', 'Kalimpong']
Veg_Toppings = ['Cappsicum', 'Olives', 'Onions', 'Jalapeno', 'Mushroom', 'Babycorn', 'Potato', 'Paneer']
Non_Veg_Toppings = ['Chicken Tikka', 'Chicken CHilly', 'Chicken Crispy', 'Chicken Masala', 'Chicken Hara Bhara', 'Chicken Kashmiri', 'Fish Fry', 'Prawn', 'Mutton', 'Ham', 'Bacon', 'Meat Sausage']
Crust_Types = ['Cheese', 'Sausage', 'Simple']
Breads = ['Thin','Thick', 'Fluffy']
Sizes = ['Mini', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra large', 'Super Sized']

print("\nBread Types")
e=1
for Bread in Breads:
    print( str(int(e)) + ". " + Bread + " Bread.")
    int(str(e))       
    e=e+1
print("Please Select your choice of Bread. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")
while True:
    g = input()
    if(g.isdigit()):
        g=int()
        g=g-1
        while True:
            if(g>=0 and g<3):
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nCrust Types")
d=1
for Crust_Type in Crust_Types:
    print( str(int(d)) + ". " + Crust_Type + " Crust.")
    int(str(d))       
    d=d+1
print("Please Select your choice of Crust Type. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")
while True:
    r = input()
    if(r.isdigit()):
        r=r-1
        while True:
            if(r>=0 and r<3):
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nPizza Sizes")
f=1
for Size in Sizes:
    print( str(int(f)) + ". " + Size + " Pizza.")
    int(str(f))       
    f=f+1
print("Please Select your choice of Pizza Size. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")
while True:
    h = input()
    if(h.isdigit()):
        h=h-1
        while True:
            if(h>=0 and h<6):
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nTypes of Cheese")
a=1
for Cheese_Type in Cheese_Types:
    print( str(int(a)) + ". " + Cheese_Type + " Cheese.")
    int(str(a))       
    a=a+1
print("Please Select your choice for the type of Cheese. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")
while True:
    i = input()
    if(i.isdigit()):
        i=i-1
        while True:
            if(i>=0 and i<17):
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nVegetarian Toppings")
b=1
for Veg_Topping in Veg_Toppings:
    print( str(int(b)) + ". " + Veg_Topping + ".")
    int(str(b))       
    b=b+1
print("Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
while True:
    j = input()
    if(j.isdigit()):
        j=j-1
        while True:
            if(j>=0 and j<8):
                l=Veg_Toppings[j] + " "
                while True:
                    print("Do you want any more Vegetarian Toppings?")
                    k = input()
                    k=k.title()
                    if(k == "Yes"):
                        print("Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
                        m = input()
                        m=m-1
                        l=l+Veg_Toppings[m]+" "
                    else:
                        break
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nNon-Vegetarian Toppings")
c=1
for Non_Veg_Topping in Non_Veg_Toppings:
    print( str(int(c)) + ". " + Non_Veg_Topping + ".")
    int(str(c))       
    c=c+1
print("Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
while True:
    n = input()
    if(n.isdigit()):
        n=n-1
        while True:
            if(n>=0 and n<12):
                o=Non_Veg_Toppings[n] + " "
                while True:
                    print("Do you want any more Non Vegetarian Toppings?")
                    p = input()
                    p=p.title()
                    if(p == "Yes"):
                        print("Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
                        q = input()
                        q=q-1
                        o=o+Non_Veg_Toppings[q]+" "
                    else:
                        break
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a numerical value")
Pizza = "You have ordered a " + Breads[g] + " Bread " + Crust_Types[r] + " Crust " + Sizes[h] + " Pizza with " + Cheese_Types[i] + " Cheese and " + l + o + "."
print(Pizza)
'''
```

It is a simple code but it won't work as it should work.
I also tried removing some code.
I also tried changing the + to -.

Comment: Share what output you are expecting from your code as well!

Comment: This is crying for an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have tried to modify your code minimally to make it work! Check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not very readable, and I have done minimal changes to make it work, I would suggest taking it from here and working on your code to make it better.

Some errors I found in your code.

1. No need of the external outer `while True` loop you have added in any of the choices.
2. At a lot of places, you have not assigned `int(variable)` to an actual variable
3. Also the variables `l` and `o` need to be defined outside the loop to make it accessible for the print statements.

```
print("Hello.\nWelcome to Pizzeria World")
Cheese_Types = ['Mozzarella', 'Parmesan', 'Ricotta', 'Feta', 'Blue Veined', 'Cheddar', 'Gouda', 'Cottage', 'Goat', 'Halloumi', 'Kalari', 'Scamorza', 'Bocconcini', 'Mascarpone', 'Gorgonzola', 'Grana Padano', 'Kalimpong']
Veg_Toppings = ['Cappsicum', 'Olives', 'Onions', 'Jalapeno', 'Mushroom', 'Babycorn', 'Potato', 'Paneer']
Non_Veg_Toppings = ['Chicken Tikka', 'Chicken CHilly', 'Chicken Crispy', 'Chicken Masala', 'Chicken Hara Bhara', 'Chicken Kashmiri', 'Fish Fry', 'Prawn', 'Mutton', 'Ham', 'Bacon', 'Meat Sausage']
Crust_Types = ['Cheese', 'Sausage', 'Simple']
Breads = ['Thin','Thick', 'Fluffy']
Sizes = ['Mini', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra large', 'Super Sized']

print("\nBread Types")
e=1
for Bread in Breads:
    print( str(int(e)) + ". " + Bread + " Bread.")
    int(str(e))
    e=e+1
print("Please Select your choice of Bread. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

g = input()
if(g.isdigit()):
    g=int(g)
    g=g-1
    while True:
        if(g>=0 and g<3):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nCrust Types")
d=1
for Crust_Type in Crust_Types:
    print( str(int(d)) + ". " + Crust_Type + " Crust.")
    d = int(str(d))
    d=d+1
print("Please Select your choice of Crust Type. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

r = input()
if(r.isdigit()):
    r = int(r)
    r=r-1
    while True:
        if(r>=0 and r<3):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nPizza Sizes")
f=1
for Size in Sizes:
    print( str(int(f)) + ". " + Size + " Pizza.")
    f = int(str(f))
    f=f+1
print("Please Select your choice of Pizza Size. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

h = input()
if(h.isdigit()):
    h = int(h)
    h=h-1
    while True:
        if(h>=0 and h<6):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")

else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nTypes of Cheese")
a=1
for Cheese_Type in Cheese_Types:
    print( str(int(a)) + ". " + Cheese_Type + " Cheese.")
    int(str(a))
    a=a+1

print("Please Select your choice for the type of Cheese. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

i = input()
if(i.isdigit()):
    i = int(i)
    i=i-1
    while True:
        if(i>=0 and i<17):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nVegetarian Toppings")
b=1
for Veg_Topping in Veg_Toppings:
    print( str(int(b)) + ". " + Veg_Topping + ".")
    b = int(str(b))
    b=b+1
print("Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )

j = input()
l = " "
if(j.isdigit()):
    j = int(j)
    j=j-1
    while True:
        if(j>=0 and j<8):
            l=Veg_Toppings[j] + " "
            while True:
                print("Do you want any more Vegetarian Toppings?")
                k = input()
                k=k.title()
                if(k == "Yes"):
                    print("Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
                    m = input()
                    m = int(m)
                    m=m-1
                    l=l+Veg_Toppings[m]+" "
                else:
                    break
        break
else:
    print("Please enter a value from the menu")


print("\nNon-Vegetarian Toppings")
c=1
for Non_Veg_Topping in Non_Veg_Toppings:
    print( str(int(c)) + ". " + Non_Veg_Topping + ".")
    c = int(str(c))
    c=c+1
print("Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )

n = input()
o = " "
if(n.isdigit()):
    n = int(n)
    n=n-1
    while True:
        if(n>=0 and n<12):
            o=Non_Veg_Toppings[n] + " "
            while True:
                print("Do you want any more Non Vegetarian Toppings?")
                p = input()
                p=p.title()
                if(p == "Yes"):
                    print("Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
                    q = input()
                    q = int(q)
                    q=q-1
                    o=o+Non_Veg_Toppings[q]+" "
                else:
                    break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break

else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

Pizza = "You have ordered a {} Bread {} Crust {} Pizza with {} Cheese and {} {}.".format(Breads[g],Crust_Types[r], Sizes[h], Cheese_Types[i], l , o)
print(Pizza)
```

The output now looks like.

```
Hello.
Welcome to Pizzeria World

Bread Types
1. Thin Bread.
2. Thick Bread.
3. Fluffy Bread.
Please Select your choice of Bread. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.
1

Crust Types
1. Cheese Crust.
2. Sausage Crust.
3. Simple Crust.
Please Select your choice of Crust Type. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.
1

Pizza Sizes
1. Mini Pizza.
2. Small Pizza.
3. Medium Pizza.
4. Large Pizza.
5. Extra large Pizza.
6. Super Sized Pizza.
Please Select your choice of Pizza Size. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.
1

Types of Cheese
1. Mozzarella Cheese.
2. Parmesan Cheese.
3. Ricotta Cheese.
4. Feta Cheese.
5. Blue Veined Cheese.
6. Cheddar Cheese.
7. Gouda Cheese.
8. Cottage Cheese.
9. Goat Cheese.
10. Halloumi Cheese.
11. Kalari Cheese.
12. Scamorza Cheese.
13. Bocconcini Cheese.
14. Mascarpone Cheese.
15. Gorgonzola Cheese.
16. Grana Padano Cheese.
17. Kalimpong Cheese.
Please Select your choice for the type of Cheese. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.
1

Vegetarian Toppings
1. Cappsicum.
2. Olives.
3. Onions.
4. Jalapeno.
5. Mushroom.
6. Babycorn.
7. Potato.
8. Paneer.
Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.
1
Do you want any more Vegetarian Toppings?
No

Non-Vegetarian Toppings
1. Chicken Tikka.
2. Chicken CHilly.
3. Chicken Crispy.
4. Chicken Masala.
5. Chicken Hara Bhara.
6. Chicken Kashmiri.
7. Fish Fry.
8. Prawn.
9. Mutton.
10. Ham.
11. Bacon.
12. Meat Sausage.
Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.
1
Do you want any more Non Vegetarian Toppings?
No
You have ordered a Thin Bread Cheese Crust Mini Pizza with Mozzarella Cheese and Cappsicum  Chicken Tikka .
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code you just change the while loop and run it so its work properly. I have posted new code here, please refer it.

```
print("Hello.\nWelcome to Pizzeria World")
Cheese_Types = ['Mozzarella', 'Parmesan', 'Ricotta', 'Feta', 'Blue Veined', 'Cheddar', 'Gouda', 'Cottage', 'Goat', 'Halloumi', 'Kalari', 'Scamorza', 'Bocconcini', 'Mascarpone', 'Gorgonzola', 'Grana Padano', 'Kalimpong']
Veg_Toppings = ['Cappsicum', 'Olives', 'Onions', 'Jalapeno', 'Mushroom', 'Babycorn', 'Potato', 'Paneer']
Non_Veg_Toppings = ['Chicken Tikka', 'Chicken CHilly', 'Chicken Crispy', 'Chicken Masala', 'Chicken Hara Bhara', 'Chicken Kashmiri', 'Fish Fry', 'Prawn', 'Mutton', 'Ham', 'Bacon', 'Meat Sausage']
Crust_Types = ['Cheese', 'Sausage', 'Simple']
Breads = ['Thin','Thick', 'Fluffy']
Sizes = ['Mini', 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra large', 'Super Sized']

print("\nBread Types")
e=1
for Bread in Breads:
    print( str(int(e)) + ". " + Bread + " Bread.")
    int(str(e))
    e=e+1
print("Please Select your choice of Bread. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

g = input()
if(g.isdigit()):
    g=int(g)
    g=g-1
    while True:
        if(g>=0 and g<3):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nCrust Types")
d=1
for Crust_Type in Crust_Types:
    print( str(int(d)) + ". " + Crust_Type + " Crust.")
    d = int(str(d))
    d=d+1
print("Please Select your choice of Crust Type. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

r = input()
if(r.isdigit()):
    r = int(r)
    r=r-1
    while True:
        if(r>=0 and r<3):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nPizza Sizes")
f=1
for Size in Sizes:
    print( str(int(f)) + ". " + Size + " Pizza.")
    f = int(str(f))
    f=f+1
print("Please Select your choice of Pizza Size. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

h = input()
if(h.isdigit()):
    h = int(h)
    h=h-1
    while True:
        if(h>=0 and h<6):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")

else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nTypes of Cheese")
a=1
for Cheese_Type in Cheese_Types:
    print( str(int(a)) + ". " + Cheese_Type + " Cheese.")
    int(str(a))
    a=a+1

print("Please Select your choice for the type of Cheese. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu.")

i = input()
if(i.isdigit()):
    i = int(i)
    i=i-1
    while True:
        if(i>=0 and i<17):
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

print("\nVegetarian Toppings")
b=1
for Veg_Topping in Veg_Toppings:
    print( str(int(b)) + ". " + Veg_Topping + ".")
    b = int(str(b))
    b=b+1
print("Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )

j = input()

if(j.isdigit()):
    j = int(j)
    j=j-1
    while True:
        if(j>=0 and j<8):
            l=Veg_Toppings[j] + " "
            while True:
                print("Do you want any more Vegetarian Toppings?")
                k = input()
                k=k.title()
                if(k == "Yes"):
                    print("Please Select your choice for the Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
                    m = input()
                    m = int(m)
                    m=m-1
                    l=l+Veg_Toppings[m]+" "
                else:
                    break
        break
else:
    print("Please enter a value from the menu")


print("\nNon-Vegetarian Toppings")
c=1
for Non_Veg_Topping in Non_Veg_Toppings:
    print( str(int(c)) + ". " + Non_Veg_Topping + ".")
    c = int(str(c))
    c=c+1
print("Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )

n = input()

if(n.isdigit()):
    n = int(n)
    n=n-1
    while True:
        if(n>=0 and n<12):
            o=Non_Veg_Toppings[n] + " "
            while True:
                print("Do you want any more Non Vegetarian Toppings?")
                p = input()
                p=p.title()
                if(p == "Yes"):
                    print("Please Select your choice for the Non Vegetarian Toppings. Please ensure your input is numerical as per the given Menu." )
                    q = input()
                    q = int(q)
                    q=q-1
                    o=o+Non_Veg_Toppings[q]+" "
                else:
                    break
        else:
            print("Please enter a value from the menu")
        break

else:
    print("Please enter a numerical value")

Pizza = "You have ordered a " + Breads[g] + " Bread " + Crust_Types[r] + " Crust " + Sizes[h] + " Pizza with " + Cheese_Types[i] + " Cheese and " + l + o + "."
print(Pizza)
```